# Component modeling in Eclipse

Tags: object, interface, components, class-diagram, object-model

I want to make a component model using Eclipse (and possibly some plugins?) - and the corresponding object-model for the objects within the component. This web page has an example of the component model and object model I am trying to produce.
http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/componentDiagram.htm  (please look at the diagrams)

To be honest I am new to eclipse. I want BOTH the diagram and the classes and interface definitions as well (not just a picture). But I also want the picture..... not just class and component definitions. I'm running on Windows.

Are there special plugins for diagrams?

Are there special plugins for component models?

How in Eclipse do you place the classes in a component?

Any links to examples (other than the one I have), would be so appreciated!!

Thanks In Advance!!

Alex